# Flutter web is there any way to compress the image?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I've checked following plug-ins:

1. flutter_image_compress - doesn't support web
2. flutter_native_image - doesn't support web
3. image_picker - supports web
   It has imagequality param to compress image. But this doesn't work for web. I've tested myself and there is an open issue for the same:
   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78170

Does anyone know how to support image compression for flutter web?

Comment: what image do you want to compress? you mean that [Image](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Image-class.html) class?

Comment: I'm not talking about image class. My use case is pick an image from the client machine and upload it to the server. I'm using image_picker to select the image. And I want to compress the image before uploading it to the server.

Comment: so it is already compressed: for example if you pick any `.png` or `.webp` or `.jpg` image file then compressing that image is pointless since it is already compressed

Comment: I've jpg image which is 4 MB. On android I can set imagequality in image_picker to 25 and reduce the size to few hundred kbs before uploading it. The same code in image_picker doesnt work on web to reduce size. And there is no altrenative pluging for web to compress the image to reduce its size.